# SAPUI5 restore app state after reload page

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'm trying to save the app state (filter values) of my custom developed app so that I can restore them after the user is reloading the page.

Restore the app state after navigating to a different app and then coming back is already working, but somehow the app state is always empty the user reloads the page.

Does someone know if I have to do something special to persist the app state?

I'm using the CrossApplicationNavigation Service

```
this.navigator = sap.ushell.Container.getService("CrossApplicationNavigation");
...

this.navigator.getAppState(this.getOwnerComponent(), Key)
    .done(function (appState) {
                            that._appStateRestoreData(appState.getData());
                    });
```

Comment: You have to persist your state with localStorage , sessionStorage (not on tab close) or on serverside to load it back after reloading the page. A reload is the same as you would close the tab and reopen it.

Comment: use localStorage to persist your model and reinitialize it based on the stored values